# Wearing tights while doing squats and deadlifts

Tags: squats, deadlifts, tight

Is it healthy to wear tights while doing squats and deadlifts?
I bought a pair of tights and did some squats and deadlifts, not problems at all but I am just worried whether it is healthy to do so or not. I mean the compression won't interfere with the muscle who are performing some heavy lifts and then need space to get the blood pumped into them?

Comment: Are these explicit compression tights, or just regular tights? Do they provide mechanical support during your movements?

Comment: @SeanDuggan I bough AlphaSkin tights from Adidas, I believe those are compression tights.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not coming up with much yet other than a lot of speculation, and a decent amount of evidence that it's helpful to prevent soreness when worn after exercise.

Answer (score 4):

Wearing compression tights at the gym has definitely become more common throughout the years. Various athletes now partake claiming different benefits: IE yogi’s for tighter clothing and ease in mobility, runner’s for anti-chaffing, some folks opt in purely for style.

For weightlifting, some have indulged in the trend for shin protection (when weights bounce back/drop) or claim additional support around the knee area.

There have been [scientific studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6341249/)
that also show wearing compression tights contributes to faster recovery, particularly *“after intense exercise with a pronounced eccentric aspect.”*

The thought behind it is that wearing compression gear is said to trigger the acceleration of blood flow and increase oxygen delivery to the specific muscle groups (that are wearing the garment). This may allow you to workout at a higher rate for a longer time and recover faster by reducing the build of up lactic-acid.

Overall, the [evidence](https://us.humankinetics.com/blogs/excerpt/compression-garments-may-be-beneficial-to-recovery-process) around benefits of compression tights ultimately are focused on [recovery](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26522739/).

No concerns around performing specific movements like squats and deadlifts wearing the clothing is prevalent and ultimately it could be a beneficial accessory to your lifting routine and post workout muscle recovery!